# Printing a file at a given path/location

Tags: java

I want to do the following in Java:

1. I have a file path on local system( " doc\reports.pdf")
2. give it to printer or set the printer to print this file at this location.
3. pop print dialogue to the user and let him choose the properties for print.
4. print the file.

I tried using `java.print.awt` package and tried `jasperprint` to do this but did not seem to have worked.

Comment: You should research a bit more. This question seems just like "please do my job for me".

Comment: At the very least, show us what you have tried (v.g., with java.print) and why did it fail so we can help it with you. A simple "does not work" sounds a lot like "I have no idea where to start and I want someone to do it for me". Showing a code and saying "I expected A but get B" shows effort and makes it easier to give you directions to solve that puntual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using java.awt.Desktop print method you can print a File object using the native desktop printing facility.

Comment: Thank you dan it worked ! :) I spent like two days on this , I am a newbie to Java and this was hard to find out. Thank you again

Comment: Is there a way I can pop up a print dialogue box using desktop print ?